# How to remove numbers in string from json using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, ng-options

i'm working on Angular. The Api in the code passes the json value with string which  includes numbers and alphabets in it. But my  requirement is to  show only  the alphabets and remove the numbers from  the string  in my  dropdownlist .

My script :

```
staffService.getBaseBranches()
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.baseBranches = data;

    })
    .error(function(error, status) {
      showError(error, status);
      notificationFactory.error("Unable to load base branches.");
    });
```

My html :

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Branch : <i class="mandate">*</i></label>
           <select class="form-control input-md" name='branchName' ng-model="query.branchName" ng-options="branch.branchName as branch.branchName for branch in baseBranches">

           <option value="" selected>-- Select Branch --</option>
            </select>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="search_form.branchName.$error.required">Branch is required</span>
</div>
```

How can i  do this ? Please help me from this .

Comment: Provide sample json for reference.

Comment: @ Sumit here is the json [
  {
    
    "branchName": "2343 hyderabad",
    "branchCode": "2343"
  },
  {
    
    "branchName": "6768 Bangalore",
    "branchCode": "6768"
  },
  {
    
    "branchName": "5657 chennai",
    "branchCode": "5657"
  }
  ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `change` branchName while displaying it by calling `showName` function. `showName` will take care of removing `digits` from `string`

```
ng-options="branch.branchName as showName(branch.branchName) for branch in baseBranches"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.showName = function(branchName ){
   return branchName.replace(/\d+/g, '')
}
```

Comment: @  Pankaj Parkar  Can u tell me how to  use  this in my  expression in Angular

Comment: I don't understand, what is the question?

Comment: @  Pankaj Parkar  Your answer works perfectly , but  how can i use this in  my  {{}} expression.

Comment: @ Pankaj as soon  as i select the drop down the value should come inside  the Angular expression . What is the changes i should do in  my  ng-model

Comment: You can't use `{{}}` inside ng-options directive